# Proof that $\,\lim\limits_{x\to 1}\frac{\sqrt{x^2+3}-2}{2-x-x^2}=-\frac{1}{6}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I want to show by epsilon-delta that $\,\lim\limits_{x\to 1}\frac{\sqrt{x^2+3}-2}{2-x-x^2}=-\frac{1}{6}$. Note that

$$\left|\frac{\sqrt{x^2+3}-2}{2-x-x^2}+\frac{1}{6} \right|=\left|\frac{\sqrt{x^2+3}-2+\frac{1}{6}(2-x-x^2)}{(2-x-x^2)} \right|=\left|\frac{-\sqrt{x^2+3}-2+\frac{1}{6}(x-1)(x+2)}{(x-1)(x+2)} \right|$$

Now, starting from the latter seems a little difficult, if I choose $\delta_{1}=1$ we have that $\frac{1}{|x+2|}<2$ then

$$\left|\frac{-\sqrt{x^2+3}-2+\frac{1}{6}(x-1)(x+2)}{(x-1)(x+2)} \right|<\left|\frac{-\sqrt{x^2+3}-2+\frac{1}{6}(x-1)4}{(x-1) 2} \right|$$

I don't see how to bounded more terms, any help for this? thanks!

Comment: Do you only wish to find the limit? Or you need help to proceed with solution in your line of thought?

Comment: @Learningstill I need help in determining the value of delta, in order to get the demonstration on track.

Comment: Doesnt L'hospital rule help here ?

Comment: If you want to prove by bounding, you have to bound: $\frac{\sqrt{x^2+3}-2}{x-1}$. Rest of the terms does not matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $x \in \mathbb{R} \backslash \{ 1,-2\}$, we have that
$$
\frac{\sqrt{x^2+3}-2}{2-x-x^2} = \frac{\sqrt{x^2+3}-2}{-(x-1)(x+2)}= \frac{x^2-1}{-(x-1)(x+2)(\sqrt{x^2+3}+2)} = \frac{x+1}{-(x+2)(\sqrt{x^2+3}+2)}. 
$$
So we have that, if $f : \mathbb{R} \backslash \{1,-2\} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined for each $x \in \mathbb{R} \backslash \{1,-2\}$ as $f(x) = \frac{\sqrt{x^2+3}-2}{2-x-x^2}$,
$$
\left| f(x) -(-\frac{1}{6}) \right| = \left| \frac{x+1}{-(x+2)(\sqrt{x^2+3}+2)} + \frac{1}{6} \right| = \left| \frac{(x-1) + 2 - \frac{1}{6}[(x+2)(\sqrt{x^2+3}+2)] }{(x+2)(\sqrt{x^2+3}+2)}\right|
$$

Assume that
$|x-1| \leq 1$ to start.
Then you have that, $|x+2| \leq 4$, $\frac{1}{|x+2|} \leq \frac{1}{2}$,$|\sqrt{x^2+3}+2| \leq 5$ and $\frac{1}{|\sqrt{x^2+3}+2|} \leq \frac{1}{3}$.
So you have that, for all $x \in \mathbb{R} \backslash \{ 1,-2\} $, with $|x-1| \leq 1$,
\begin{equation}
\left| \frac{(x-1) + 2 - \frac{1}{6}[(x+2)(\sqrt{x^2+3}+2)] }{(x+2)(\sqrt{x^2+3}+2)}\right| \leq \left| \frac{(x-1) + 2 - \frac{5.4}{6}}{6}\right| = \left| \frac{(x-1)- \frac{4}{3}}{6}\right| \leq  \frac{|x-1|}{6}. 
\end{equation}

We can now show that $f$ as a limit, -$\frac{1}{6}$, evaluated in $1$. 
Let $\epsilon > 0$, if $\delta = \min\{1,6\epsilon\} $, we have that for each $x \in \mathbb{R} \backslash \{1,-2\}$, with $|x-1| \leq \delta$,
\begin{equation}
\left| f(x) -(-\frac{1}{6}) \right| = \left| \frac{(x-1) + 2 - \frac{1}{6}[(x+2)(\sqrt{x^2+3}+2)] }{(x+2)(\sqrt{x^2+3}+2)}\right| \leq  \frac{|x-1|}{6} \leq  \frac{6\epsilon}{6} = \epsilon. 
\end{equation}
This proves that $f$ does have a limit in $1$, which is -$\frac{1}{6}$.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how much it helps, but you can rearrange the proposed expression in order to get:
\begin{align*}
\left|\frac{\sqrt{x^{2} + 3} - 2}{2 - x - x^{2}} + \frac{1}{6}\right| & = \left|\frac{x^{2} - 1}{(1 - x)(x + 2)(\sqrt{x^{2} + 3} + 2)} + \frac{1}{6}\right|\\\\
& = \left|\frac{(x + 2)(\sqrt{x^{2} + 3} + 2) - 6(x + 1)}{6(x + 2)(\sqrt{x^{2} + 3} + 2)}\right|\\\\
& = \left|\frac{(x + 1)(\sqrt{x^{2} + 3} - 4) + \sqrt{x^{2} + 3} + 2}{6(x + 2)(\sqrt{x^{2} + 3} + 2)}\right|
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Change variables to $x=1+\varepsilon$, so that the limit becomes
$$\lim\limits_{\varepsilon\to 0}\dfrac{\sqrt{\left(1+\varepsilon\right)^2+3}-2}{2-(1+\varepsilon)-(1+\varepsilon)^2}.$$
Now the terms in the numerator and denominator can be expanded in powers of $\varepsilon$, and retaining only the terms linear in $\varepsilon$, gives the required limit as
$$\dfrac{\sqrt{1+2\varepsilon+3}-2}{1-\varepsilon-(1+2\varepsilon)}=
 -\dfrac{2\left(1+\tfrac{2\varepsilon}{8}\right)-2}{3\varepsilon}=-\dfrac{1}{6}.$$

Comment: The first equality in the second line seems a bit strange. I mean, I get what you're trying to say, but that equality is not technically correct (if $\varepsilon$ is a real number).

Comment: Yes, sorry about omitting the Order symbols.

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{array}\\
\lim\limits_{x\to 1}\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2+3}-2}{2-x-x^2}
&=\lim\limits_{y\to 0}\dfrac{\sqrt{(1+y)^2+3}-2}{2-(1+y)-(1+y)^2}
\qquad\text{Want to have values go to zero}\\
&=\lim\limits_{y\to 0}\dfrac{\sqrt{4+2y+y^2}-2}{1-y-(1+2y+y^2)}\\
&=\lim\limits_{y\to 0}\dfrac{\sqrt{4+2y+y^2}-2}{-3y-y^2}\dfrac{\sqrt{4+2y+y^2}+2}{\sqrt{4+2y+y^2}+2}
\qquad\text{The usual conjugate}\\
&=\lim\limits_{y\to 0}\dfrac{(4+2y+y^2)-4}{(-3y-y^2)(\sqrt{4+2y+y^2}+2)}\\
&=\lim\limits_{y\to 0}\dfrac{2y+y^2}{(-3y-y^2)(\sqrt{4+2y+y^2}+2)}\\
&=\lim\limits_{y\to 0}\dfrac{2+y}{(-3-y)(\sqrt{4+2y+y^2}+2)}\qquad\text{Divide top and bottom by }y\\
&=\lim\limits_{y\to 0}\dfrac{2}{(-3)(2+2)}
\qquad\text{Now can replace }y\text{ by zero since }
4 < 4+2y+y^2 < 4+4y+y^2=(2+y)^2\\
&=-\dfrac16\\\end{array}
$

Comment: Thanks for your support, but I didn't understand very well why you say that you can replace y by zero (the penultimate line), could you help me a little?

Answer (score 1):

After messing around, I've found a way to solve it. I don't have much experience in delta-epsilon method so this will be a bit tedious lol. Any suggestions for improvement are welcome.

First I chose to rationalize the nominator because maybe that would help.
$$
\frac{\sqrt{x^2+3}-2}{2-x-x^2}
= \frac{x^2-1}{(2-x-x^2) (\sqrt{x^2+3}+2)}
= \frac{-(x+1)}{(x+2) (\sqrt{x^2+3}+2)}
$$

I will limit the domain because this will be helpful later. Let $D = (0.6, 1.3) \setminus \{ 1 \}$. Let function $f: D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the above function:

$$
f(x) = \frac{-(x+1)}{(x+2) (\sqrt{x^2+3}+2)}
$$
Now your problem becomes proving that

$$
\lim_{x \to 1} f(x) = \frac{-1}{6}
$$

Given $\epsilon > 0$, choose $\delta = ...$ (this blank will be filled later).
Suppose $0 < |x-1| < \delta$. Consider $|f(x) + \frac{1}{6}|$:

$$
\left|f(x) + \frac{1}{6}\right| \\
= \left| \frac{x\sqrt{x^2+3} + 2\sqrt{x^2+3} - 4x - 2}{6(x+2)(\sqrt{x^2+3}+2)} \right| \\
< \left| x\sqrt{x^2+3} + 2\sqrt{x^2+3} - 4x - 2 \right| \\
= \left| (x+2)\sqrt{x^2+3} - 2(2x+1) \right| \\
\leq \left| (x+2)\sqrt{x^2+3} - 2(x+2) \right| (*) (\text{more on this later}) \\
= \left| (x+2)(\sqrt{x^2+3}-2) \right| \\
= \left| (x+2)\frac{x^2-1}{\sqrt{x^2+3}+2} \right| \\
< \left| (x+2)(x^2-1) \right| \\
= \left| (x+2)(x+1)(x-1) \right| \\
< \left| (x+2)(x+1) \right| \delta
$$
Now, since we have limited the domain such that $0.6 < x < 1.3$, we have $|(x+2)(x+1)| < 4.29$. So we can continue:

$$
< 4.29 \delta \\
= \epsilon
$$

Now if we come back and choose $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{4.29}$, then the proof is complete.

But there's still (*) that we need to prove:
$$
\left| (x+2)\sqrt{x^2+3} - 2(2x+1) \right| \leq \left| (x+2)\sqrt{x^2+3} - 2(x+2) \right|
$$

According to [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%5Cleft%7C%20%28x%2B2%29%5Csqrt%7Bx%5E2%2B3%7D%20-%202%282x%2B1%29%20%5Cright%7C%20%3C%3D%20%5Cleft%7C%20%28x%2B2%29%5Csqrt%7Bx%5E2%2B3%7D%20-%202%28x%2B2%29%20%5Cright%7C), this is true when $x \in (-\infty, -4.08] \cup [0.51, +\infty)$, which is a superset of our domain $D$. I haven't found out how to prove this without dealing with some cubic equation madness yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prove by bounding you have bound the term $$\frac{\sqrt{x^2+3}-2}{x-1}$$.

$$\frac{(\sqrt{x^2+3}-2) \times (\sqrt{x^2+3}+2)}{(x-1)(\sqrt{x^2+3}+2)}$$
$$\frac{x^2+3-4}{(x-1)(\sqrt{x^2+3}+2)}$$
$$\frac{x^2-1}{(x-1)(\sqrt{x^2+3}+2)}$$
$$\frac{x+1}{(\sqrt{x^2+3}+2)} \rightarrow 1/2$$ as $x \rightarrow 1$

Hence the original limit goes to $-1/6$